# How to use PayPalApplicationId

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, paypal

I am starting with the integration of Pay Pal APIs and library into one of my Apps.I have gone through the documentation and source code provided by Pay Pal.My query is How do i use PayPalApplicationId in my application.From what i interpret from the documentation provided by Pay Pal is that it would be provided by Pay Pal once i have completed development of my App and after i submit it to Pay Pal , i will receive it from them.So how do i begin the integration without PayPalApplicationId.Do i use the one provided in the sample code?
Secondly whats the use of PayPalApplicationId?

Cheers

Aditya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PayPalApplicationID` makes your app unique from other apps using the PayPal API.

```
+(PayPal*)initializeWithAppID:(NSString const *)PayPalApplicationID (Optional:) forEnvironment:PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT)env;
```

Take from [PP_MPL_Developer_Guide_and_Reference_iPhone.pdf](https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-2534).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the integration in sandbox environment.
You use following id for that purpose "APP-80W284485P519543T"